# Using @package instead of namespace in PhpDocumentor 2

Tags: php, namespaces, phpdoc, docblocks, phpdocumentor2

I have a large code library for which I am trying to generate hierarchical documentation. The project does not use namespaces but uses @package instead.

I just tried generating docs as a test from the following file with phpDocumentor2:

```
<?php
/**
 * This is a file
 * @package JustAn\Example
 **/

 /**
 * Something class
 **/
 class Something{
    function try_this(){

    }
 }
```

Though according to the docs @package JustAn\Example should be the equivalent of namespace JustAn\Example, I found this not to be the case.

When I use namespaces the resulting documentation is like this:

[image: namespace version]

When I use the @package notation the result looks like this (even though it recognizes the package notation - this is shown on the full details page of the class):

[image: package notation version]

I am looking for a way to get the hierarchical result without having to rewrite the code to use 'real' namespaces.

Comment: There does seem to be an issue with @package at the moment. See https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1133

Comment: This seems to be unrelated because the @package tag is registered, it just does not result in the same hiearchical listing. I've created an issue for it: https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor2/issues/1155

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the default "clean" template does not support this feature. Other templates (like "responsive" for example) do. You can use the --template="responsive" flag to change the default template used.

Comment: This doesn't fix the issue I am having. Did you actually get this working or are you just going by mvriel's answer in the issue thread?

Comment: These templates worked: "responsive", "responsive-twig" worked.

Comment: I wish this can be added by phpdoc team in the future. Meantime, I just confirm "responsive" or "responsive-twig" works for me, although it doesn't look as nice as "clean". Another thought, we probably should use namespace !

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have the package tag in the *file* docblock, but not the *class* docblock.  If you add it to your class docblock, I think it should work.

Comment: Just tried setting it on the class level too - the result is the same: no namespace hierarchy is present in the list.